# Ordering the graph nodes in networkx

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I have created a graph using NetworkX with objects as nodes using python2. Currently i am changing to python3 and get nodes from graph gives the result in random order everytime whereas in python2 it is same order all the time .

```
import networkx as nx

class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

graph = nx.Graph()

obj1 = Cell('A')
obj2 = Cell('B')
obj3 = Cell('C')

graph.add_nodes_from({obj1,obj2,obj3})

print(graph.nodes())
```

**Output:** Python 2:

[B, C, A]

[B, C, A]

[B, C, A]

**Python 3:**

[C, B, A]

[B, C, A]

[A, C, B]

What is the reason for order changes everytime. Is there anyway i can get the same order as like in python2. I do not want to sort the order instead getting the same order like python 2 gives.

Comment: Same deal for nodes - you can't. A network is not supposed to have a defined order, and likely dropping the guarantee allows to optimize.

Comment: Although this is a duplicate, it should be noted that the old question is out of date.  Networkx now provides an ordered graph implementation as well: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/ordered.html